# Marshalling "as string" parameter from C#

Tags: c#, string, marshalling

Ran into an interesting problem that I was wondering if anyone can help explain.  I have tried searching all over the internet and can’t seem to find an answer to this problem.  While we have a solution, others might run into the same problem, and since it was random, it is very hard to track down.

We have an application that randomly fails when the computer is attached to the customers corporate network (don’t have a lot of information on the network).  When we brought the computer to our environment it worked fine.  The failure is fairly random, but as best as I could figure out occurred during calls from C# to an unmanaged third party vendors DLL.  One of the trace backs I do have (only a couple failures provided traces in the system event log) points to a failure in ntdll.dll in the RtlMoveMemory function during the marshalling of parameters in calls to the unmanaged DLL.

The call to the unmanaged function was:

```
ThirdParty.CxxxAutomationWrapper clientDLL = new ThirdParty.CxxxAutomationWrapper () ;

object Parameter1 ;
  :
string theValue = "abcde" ;
Parameter1 = theValue ;
  :
if ( Parameter1 is string )
{
    int returnCode = clientDLL.function ( Parameter1 as string ) ;
}
```

The call periodically fails on the customers computer but always works when run within Visual Studio (2010).  The value of Parameter1 is correctly set (never null).

Since I changed the call to:

```
String parameter1String = Parameter1.ToString() ;
int returnCode = clientDLL.function ( parameter1String ) ;
```

everything has worked fine.  The value of Parameter1 is very controlled and is not null prior to this code being executed.

The interface being called (clientDLL.function) is defined as:

```
HRESULT function ( [in] BSTR parameter,
                   [out, retval] long *ret);
```

With my [limited?] understanding of the ‘as’ statement in c#, I don’t understand why the first version of this failed.  Can anybody help explain why this fails when called with the parameter specified as “as string”?

Comment: Updated the original post in response to answers that I recieved to help clarify the problem.  Updates include showing how Parameter1 is declared and assigned, and putting an if (Parameter1 is string) around the call as suggested by Tudor.

Comment: Can you try to log for which values of `Parameter1` the crash occurs? Can you see any pattern?

Comment: I have coded the exact code shown above, hardcoding the assignment to a string variable initializing it with "abcde" and assigning that variable to Parameter1 testing it via the if (Parameter1 is string) and it still works fine in Visual Studio but fails outside of VS (sometimes).

Comment: Then maybe the dll call has some hidden bugs?

Comment: @Tudor: When I get a call stack (in the System Event Log) it shows:  at ThirdParty.ICxxxAutomationWrapper.function (System.String) at   myfunction  In other words it shows it in the interface wrapper but then references a location in ntdll.dll as the point of the access violation.  It does not show the ThirdParty Client dll in the stack or as the point of failure.  I believe that means that it hasn't gotten to the DLL yet.  Am I reading that wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Because `obj as string` and `obj.ToString()` are not the same. The first is an attempted cast (sort of like `(string)obj`, but which returns `null` upon failure), while the seconds is a method call returning a string representation of the object.

Practically you can get the string representation of any object regardless of whether it's compatible with string as type, but the cast will fail if they are not compatible.

Simple example:

```
object obj = new object(); // simple object
Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString()); // prints System.Object
Console.WriteLine((obj as string) == null); // True: obj is not a string!
```

Comment: I have since updated my sample code to show that Parameter1 always contains a valid string object.  Also I am having trouble with the random-ness of the error and the fact that there is not a problem running within Visual Studio.

Comment: @RichardBousman: So you are certain that `Parameter1` is always a valid string? I could see the situation you mentioned happening in case you are sometimes passing a non-string by mistake, such that `as string` fails, but `ToString` doesn't.

Comment: Yes. If it were not, I believe it would 1) always fail 2) fail within Visual Studio. The parameter is checked several times prior to this point. The code referenced above is in a DLL. The code is in a managed DLL. The string is originally passed into the managed DLL from an unmanaged C++ DLL.

Comment: @Richard Bousman: How about adding a compatibility test using the `is` operator, before trying to do the cast to string. Like `if(Parameter1 is string)...`. This will ensure that the underlying value of `Parameter1` is indeed a valid string.

Comment: Putting an if (Parameter1 is string) around the call still fails with an AccessViolation on the call to clientDLL.function.

Answer (score 2):

`Parameter1.ToString()` will render any .NET object to a string (i.e. instance of `System.String`). `Parameter1 as string` will return `null` if `Parameter1` is null **or if it is not an instance of `System.String`**. If it is a class that wraps a string rather than actually *being* one, then you will end up with a `null`.

Neither will work in every case of course. If you have an instance of `System.String` which is `null`, then `Parameter1 as string` would correctly return `null`, whereas `Parameter1.ToString()` would throw a `NullReferenceException`.

A safe approach would be: `Convert.ToString(Parameter1)`.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I have since updated the original post to show that Parameter1 is always a valid string.

Answer (score 0):

`Parameter1 as string` could be thought as

```
string foo
try
{
    foo = (string)Parameter1;
}
catch
{
    foo = null;
}
```

where `.ToString()` is

```
string foo = Parameter1.ToString();
```

The fact that Parameter1 is not directly castable to a string is the reson for it failing.